# source.uri is null coming from aws on react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I'm sourcing the image on aws and when I run the code through i get warning  error that source.uri is null  and the image wont display. Im getting the image from the server cause  i can see the image in the debugger but it wont display in the code.

This is my action file src/actions/item.js

```
import { HOST } from '../constants';
import { normalizeItems, normalizeItem } from '../utils';
  export const SET_ITEMS = 'SET_ITEMS';
  export function setItems(items) {
      return {
           type: SET_ITEMS,
           items
      }
 }
 export function getItems() {
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
     return fetch(`${HOST}/api/v1/items`)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(json => {
      console.log("getItems", json);

      if (json.is_success) {
        dispatch(setItems(normalizeItems(json.items)));
     } else {
       alert(json.error);
     }
   })
   .catch(e => alert(e));
  }
 }
```

This the image of the debugger shows the i have the image there
[image]

This is my reducers file src/reducers/item.js

```
import { SET_ITEMS,SET_ITEM } from '../actions/item';
const initialState = {
    items: [],
};
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
if (action.type === SET_ITEMS) {
    return {
    ...state,
    items: action.items
    }
}
```

This file where i render my code src/components/MainScreen/ExploreTab.js

```
class ExploreTab extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.getItems();
}
onPress(item) {
  this.props.navigate({ routeName: "Item", params: { item: item } });
}
render() {
  const { items, filter } = this.props;
   return (
    <FlatList
    style={styles.container}
    data = { items }
    renderItem={({item}) =>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPress(item)} style={styles.item}>
      <Image style={styles.image} source = {{uri: item.image}} />
         <Text style = {styles.title}>{`$${item.price} ${item.instant ? ' ' : ''}${item.title}`}</Text>
         <Text>{`${item.itemCategory} - ${item.itemCondition} `}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      }
     keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
     />
   );
  }
}
 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    items: state.item.items
  });
 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
     navigate: (route) => dispatch(navigate(route)),
     getItems: () => dispatch(getItems()),
  });
```

if I change this line

```
<Image style={styles.image} source = {{uri: item.image}} />
```

to this I will see the image

```
<Image style={styles.image} source = {{uri: 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/borroup/photos/images/1/medium/Screen_Shot_2018-03-22_at_10.48.28_PM.png'}} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the src/utils/index.js

I had setup as

```
import { HOST } from '../constants';

export function normalizeItems(items) {
 return items.map(item => {
  return{
    id: item.id || '',
    title: item.item_name ||'',
    image: `${HOST}${item.image}` ||'',
    itemCategory: item.item_category ||'',
    itemCondition: item.item_condition ||'',
    price: item.price ||'',
    instant: item.instant ||'',
   }
 })
}
```

so i had to change

```
image: `${HOST}${item.image}` ||'',
```

to this and worked for me

```
image: `${item.image}` ||'',
```